# Why can't I use Apache's StringUtils.join on a List?

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons, apache-stringutils

When I try

```
StringUtils.join(myList,',');
```

I get a compilation failure:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method join(java.util.List,char)
```

But the following works:

```
StringUtils.join(myList.toArray(),',');
```

The [docs (Apache Commons Lang 2.5)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20char%29) seem to indicate that both should work, as they record both:

```
public static String join(Collection collection,
                      char separator)
```

and

```
public static String join(Object[] array,
                      char separator)
```

Any ideas? For the record, I'm importing `import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;`

Comment: It's available since version 2.3. Do you have an outdated JAR file?

Comment: I actually have the same problem but i've checked everything and my versions 2.6

Comment: have you tried myList.iterator?

Comment: @Kevin My issue was the version of apache-commons in my project. If you are having the same symptoms with version 2.6, you may want to ask your own question. (This question, with an accepted answer, is not likely to receive more attention.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most probable reason is, that you are using an older version of Commons Lang, since the method using a `Collection` has only been added in 2.3.

You can check that by looking in the `MANIFEST.MF` file in the Jar at the `Implementation-Version` field.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem earlier and realized it is due to the order of my import.

Once I shifted my commons JAR up the order of import, it works.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite your problem but related:

In `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`, there exists a method

```
join(Object[])
```

That doesn't take a delimiter.

```
join(Object[], char)
join(Collection, char)
```

All take delimiters (may use `String` instesad of `char`).  So if you forget the delimiter, your error message may be pointing to the wrong problem.